# Object is possibly 'undefined' in Typescript on string value ''

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript and currently converting our application from React JSX to TS so please let me know if I am misunderstanding the error.

I am getting `Object is possibly 'undefined'` on a `prop` `string` that is passed down from a parent `component`. The `string` is defined within `INITIAL_STATE` in the `parent as

```
private static INITIAL_STATE = {
  password: ''
};
```

Meaning that the `prop` for `password` in the child component should never be `undefined`. The child component is

```
interface InterfaceProps {
  onlyOneLeft?: boolean;
  isEnabled?: boolean;
  signInMethod?: any;
  onUnlink?: any;
  password?: string;
  passwordTwo?: string;
  handleFormSubmit?: any;
  handleInputChange?: any;
}

const ChildComponent = ({ password }: InterfaceProps): any => {
  const regUpCase = new RegExp('^(?=.*[A-Z])');
  const regLwCase = new RegExp('^(?=.*[a-z])');
  const regDigit = new RegExp('^(?=.*[0-9])');
  const regChar = new RegExp('^(?=.*[*@!#%&()^~{}_-])');

  const pwLength = password.length >= 8;
  const pwUpCase = regUpCase.test(password);
  const pwLwCase = regLwCase.test(password);
  const pwChar = regChar.test(password);
  const pwDigit = regDigit.test(password);
  const pwSpecial = pwChar || pwDigit;

  const isInvalid =
    !pwLength || !pwUpCase || !pwLwCase || !pwSpecial || password === '';

  return isInvalid ? (
    ... // return when password isInvalid
  ) : (
    ... // return when password !isInvalid
  );
};

ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  password: PropTypes.string
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

On `pwLength` I am seeing the error of `Object is possibly 'undefined'` on the `password` `prop`.

On `{ pwUpCase, pwLwCase, pwChar, pwDigit }` on the `password` `prop` I am getting an error of `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

My thought in this scenario is that the `props` `password` will never be `undefined` as it has an initial `state` of `''` in the parent component.

Am I required to still check for `password` to undefined? Or perhaps should the correct method be to move `isInvalid` to the parent component? I would prefer I didn't need to, so any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: You are destructuring `password` from props and accessing its `length` property, but in your props interface you've marked `password` as optional, i.e. possibly undefined so `password.length` could possibly error if the prop is not passed.

Comment: Thanks @Li357. The reason for `InterfaceProps): any` is because I also have several functions passed down too but for the question I removed those as they do not apply. Again my understanding on `any` could be misplaced.

Comment: I am not talking about `any` (though you really shouldn't be using it as the return type. You can just let TS infer). I'm talking about `password?: string` -- you've marked the password prop as optional so there is a possibility `password.length` will error because `password` is undefined which TS is telling you.

Comment: I see. That makes perfect sense. Is there any benefit of using `password: string` over the answer below by R3tep?

Comment: R3tep suggests giving the prop a default value. Your suggestion makes the prop no longer optional, so whenever you use your component, you **have** to pass `password`. Do whatever suits you, though I'd expect R3tep is more fitting (providing a default value)

Comment: Thank you, it has helped a lot with my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password` is optional on your interface.

So you need to pass a default value to `password`.

Like:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ password = '' }: InterfaceProps): any => {
-----------------------------------^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you. This did fix the error. Is there any benefit in operating this way opposed to the comment above of  changing `password?: string` to `password: string`?

Comment: This is a good question. I provid a way that respect the original interface. But if `password` is finally not optional. You can just remove `?` into the interface.